# excepción con un OpenFileDialog en vb 12 pro

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Tengo una rutina (vb 12 pro) con la que intento extraer información de una base de datos access para rellenar las celdas de varias DataGridView. La ruta del archivo .accdb que se va a cargar se obtiene mediante un OpenFileDialog. El problema es el siguiente:

La primera vez que se produce el evento Click del ToolStripMenuItem todo funciona de maravilla, se muestra el OpenFileDialog, se selecciona el archivo y los datos respectivos se cargan en las DataGrdView; pero cuando se llama nuevamente al Handler sucede que se muestra el OpenFileDialog, como cabe esperar, sin embargo, al seleccionar el archivo se produce una excepción con el siguiente mensaje: **"Intento de leer o escribir en la memoria protegida. A menudo, esto indica que hay otra memoria dañada."**

Me he valido de varios trucos para localizar el código que produce la exepción y está relacionado con esta línea: conn.open(). Cuando marco como comentarios todas la líneas de código despues de este bloque:

```
If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
     Path = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
Else
    Exit Sub
End If
```

La excepción no se produce. Se produce solamente cuando permito que se ejecute la instrucción conn.open()

He buscado por todo lado la solución a este problema y nada. Espero que puedan ayudarme con esto. En algún foro hasta se sugería que era problema de instalación del Visual o del Framework (por cierto, la versión de Framework que tengo instalada es la 4.6).

el código del handler es el que sigue:

```vb
Private Sub CargarResultadosToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CargarResultadosToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim Path As String
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim consulta As String
    Dim miTabla As DataTable
    Dim miRow As DataRow
    Dim i, indiceFila As Integer
    'Obtenemos la ruta del archivo a caragar
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Path = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim miDataGridView As DataGridView
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
    Path & "; Jet OLEDB:Database Password=4s1_3s_L4_V1d4;"
    conn.Open()
    For Each miTabPage As TabPage In ResultadosAplicacionTabControl.TabPages
        For Each miControl As Control In miTabPage.Controls
            If TypeOf (miControl) Is DataGridView Then
                miDataGridView = miControl
                If miDataGridView.Name = "DatosGeneralesDataGridView" Then
                    consulta = "SELECT * FROM DatosGenerales"
                    miTabla = ConsultarDB(consulta, conn)
                    miRow = miTabla.Rows.Item(0)
                    With miDataGridView
                        indiceFila = .Rows.Count
                        .Rows.Add()
                        .Item(0, indiceFila).Value = .Rows.Count
                        .Item(1, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(0)
                        .Item(2, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(1)
                        .Item(3, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(2)
                        .Item(4, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(3)
                        .Item(5, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(4)
                        .Item(6, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(5)
                        .Item(7, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(6)
                        .Item(8, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(7) & " (" & miRow.Item(8) & ")"
                        .Item(9, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(9)
                        .Item(10, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(10)
                        .Item(11, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(11)
                        .Item(12, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(12) & " (" & miRow.Item(13) & ")"
                        .Item(13, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(14)
                        .Item(14, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(15)
                        .Item(15, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(16)
                        .Item(16, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(17)
                        .Item(17, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(18)
                        .Item(18, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(19)
                        .Item(19, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(20)
                        .Item(20, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(21)
                    End With
                Else
                    Select Case miDataGridView.Name
                        Case "RIA_DataGridView"
                            consulta = "SELECT Respuesta, MotivoNoRespuesta FROM " & _
                                "RiesgosIntralaboralesA"
                        Case "RIB_DataGridView"
                            consulta = "SELECT Respuesta, MotivoNoRespuesta FROM " & _
                                "RiesgosIntralaboralesB"
                        Case "RE_DataGridView"
                            consulta = "SELECT Respuesta, MotivoNoRespuesta FROM " & _
                                "RiesgosExtralaborales"
                        Case "EstresDataGridView"
                            consulta = "SELECT Respuesta, MotivoNoRespuesta FROM " & _
                                "EvaluacionEstres"
                    End Select
                    miTabla = ConsultarDB(consulta, conn)
                    With miDataGridView
                        indiceFila = .Rows.Count
                        .Rows.Add()
                        .Item(0, indiceFila).Value = .Rows.Count
                        i = 1
                        For Each miRow In miTabla.Rows
                            If miRow("Respuesta") = "Sin respuesta" Then
                                .Item(i, indiceFila).Value = miRow("MotivoNoRespuesta")
                            Else
                                .Item(i, indiceFila).Value = miRow("Respuesta")
                            End If
                            i += 1
                        Next
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
    conn.Close()
    conn = Nothing
    miTabla = Nothing
    miRow = Nothing
    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

El error al que te refieres:

> Intento de leer o escribir en la memoria protegida. A menudo, esto indica que hay otra memoria dañada.

**Se manifiesta en múltiples casos** y es **difícil** de definir **cuál es la causa** por la cual se provoca.

En cada caso hay **analizar la linea** en la que te marca el debugger, que ya lo has hecho.

**Si el problema se produce** en `conn.Open()` podríamos **considerar acomodar tu código**, ya que por lo visto, no estás haciendo uso de las sentencias `Using` para tratar la conexión, y estás igualando a `Nothing` la variable de conexión al finalizar el procedimiento.

**No es un requisito excluyente** utilizar las sentencias  `Using`, de hecho las cosas que muestra tu código no son más que resultados de prueba/error con los cuales yo también me he encontrado en la misma situación de utilizar. **Sin embargo** el uso correcto de las sentencias `Using` permite **dejar de lado** todos esos **work-around** (arreglos), y olvidarnos de manipular la conexión ya que de eso se encarga automáticamente el motor.

El código adaptado con estos cambios que menciono es el siguiente:

```
 Private Sub CargarResultadosToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CargarResultadosToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim Path As String

    Dim consulta As String
    Dim miTabla As DataTable
    Dim miRow As DataRow
    Dim i, indiceFila As Integer
    'Obtenemos la ruta del archivo a caragar
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Path = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim miDataGridView As DataGridView

    Using conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Path & "; Jet OLEDB:Database Password=4s1_3s_L4_V1d4;")
        conn.Open()
        For Each miTabPage As TabPage In ResultadosAplicacionTabControl.TabPages
            For Each miControl As Control In miTabPage.Controls
                If TypeOf (miControl) Is DataGridView Then
                    miDataGridView = miControl
                    If miDataGridView.Name = "DatosGeneralesDataGridView" Then
                        miTabla = New DataTable
                        miRow = New DataRow
                        consulta = "SELECT * FROM DatosGenerales"
                        miTabla = ConsultarDB(consulta, conn)
                        miRow = miTabla.Rows.Item(0)
                        With miDataGridView
                            indiceFila = .Rows.Count
                            .Rows.Add()
                            .Item(0, indiceFila).Value = .Rows.Count
                            .Item(1, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(0)
                            .Item(2, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(1)
                            .Item(3, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(2)
                            .Item(4, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(3)
                            .Item(5, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(4)
                            .Item(6, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(5)
                            .Item(7, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(6)
                            .Item(8, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(7) & " (" & miRow.Item(8) & ")"
                            .Item(9, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(9)
                            .Item(10, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(10)
                            .Item(11, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(11)
                            .Item(12, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(12) & " (" & miRow.Item(13) & ")"
                            .Item(13, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(14)
                            .Item(14, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(15)
                            .Item(15, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(16)
                            .Item(16, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(17)
                            .Item(17, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(18)
                            .Item(18, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(19)
                            .Item(19, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(20)
                            .Item(20, indiceFila).Value = miRow.Item(21)
                        End With
                    Else
                        Select Case miDataGridView.Name
                            Case "RIA_DataGridView"
                                consulta = "SELECT Respuesta, MotivoNoRespuesta FROM " & _
                                    "RiesgosIntralaboralesA"
                            Case "RIB_DataGridView"
                                consulta = "SELECT Respuesta, MotivoNoRespuesta FROM " & _
                                    "RiesgosIntralaboralesB"
                            Case "RE_DataGridView"
                                consulta = "SELECT Respuesta, MotivoNoRespuesta FROM " & _
                                    "RiesgosExtralaborales"
                            Case "EstresDataGridView"
                                consulta = "SELECT Respuesta, MotivoNoRespuesta FROM " & _
                                    "EvaluacionEstres"
                        End Select
                        miTabla = ConsultarDB(consulta, conn)
                        With miDataGridView
                            indiceFila = .Rows.Count
                            .Rows.Add()
                            .Item(0, indiceFila).Value = .Rows.Count
                            i = 1
                            For Each miRow In miTabla.Rows
                                If miRow("Respuesta") = "Sin respuesta" Then
                                    .Item(i, indiceFila).Value = miRow("MotivoNoRespuesta")
                                Else
                                    .Item(i, indiceFila).Value = miRow("Respuesta")
                                End If
                                i += 1
                            Next
                        End With
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End Using
    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
End Sub
```

Como **última cuestión** a tener en cuenta: siempre que trabajes con una conexión a una base de datos para consultar, y  `DataTables` para llenar de información, **es importante** cerrar la conexión de la misma una vez realizado el `.Fill`, y realizar fuera de la sentencia `Using` de la conexión el bucle para recorrer los datos obtenidos.

Esto permite que no haya una conexión abierta durante demasiado tiempo sin efectuar ningún tipo de acción o consulta, y a su vez disminuye la probabilidad de posibles errores con la conexión ya que se abre-usa-cierra y luego se recorren los datos obtenidos.

Para adaptar tu código a este último punto es necesario conocer un poco más sobre la función `ConsultarDB(consulta, conn)` de tu proyecto, y modificar los bucles con los que recorres los TabPages